# Radio button on form field always submitting as ON/TRUE

Tags: php, forms, webforms

I have a fairly basic form set up with an input field for a single radio button.

There's a php script that processes the form and inserts the values into a mysql database.  For some reason, every time I fill the form out, regardless of whether I have the radio selected or not, the result is always ON/TRUE.

here is my input field:

```
<input type="radio" name="news" id="news" class="radio" value="yes" />
```

Here is part of the PHP code that is supposed to process that:

```
if(isset($_POST['news']))
{
$news = "Yes";
}
else
{
$news = "No";
}
```

Can someone tell me what hte problem is from that code or would I need to post more?

here is the full form code:

```
<form method="POST" id="ipad" name="ipad" action="list.php">
<input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'First Name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name';}" value="First Name" id="fname" name="fname" class="inputtext">


<input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Last Name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Last Name';}" value="Last Name" id="lname" name="lname" class="inputtext">

<input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" value="Email" id="email" name="email" class="inputtext">

<input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Code') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Code';}" value="Code" id="code" name="code" class="inputtext">


<input type="radio" value="" class="radio" id="news" name="news">
<div class="radiotext">sign up?</div>

  </form>
```

Notice that the radio button input has no javascript being applied to it.  I've tried filling in the value="" with YES or NO or leaving it blank.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for the radio button's *value*. The variable will always be present, so `isset()` is bound to always return true.

```
if(!empty($_POST['news']) and ($_POST['news'] == 'yes'))
```

Comment: Sorry did not work.  Answer always ends up being the same regardless.

Comment: The guy who wrote the script says I have javascript on my page that is always setting the radio button to ON but that is not the case.  The only javascript I have on there is the jquery file.  This is driving me insane

Comment: @Pekkka thanks.  I just posted the form code at the top on my original posting.

Comment: @gteh you seem to have only one radio button. Isn't the one button selected in that case anyway? The normal use case is to have multiple radio buttons. Maybe what you're looking for is a checkbox?

Comment: I tried with a checkbox too and the same thing happens.  I only have one radio button because that field is optional, so I figured if not selected, it would default to OFF.  I did switch it out for a checkbox though and I had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['news']) && $_POST['news'] == 'yes'){
    $news = "Yes";
}
else
{
   $news = "No";
}
```

Comment: testing but doesn't seem to work.. have the same issue. Only this time the answer is always NO instead of YES.

Comment: 1. print value of $_POST['news'] after submit and before this (if (isset($_POST['news']) && $_POST['news'] == 'yes')) condition comes. so we come to know what is the value of $_POST['news']. 2 If you are trying this condition with news = '' then it will give you result "No"

Answer (score 0):

about that jquery code, javascript doesn't need to be inside html to work. If I were you, I would search through my code for .attr("checked","checked") or .prop("checked");

Answer (score 0):

You need to workaround it like so...

You need to add a `hidden` input to your form and when ever you click on one of the `radio` buttons, you call a function which will change the value of the `hidden` input by its `id`.. and here it is step by step :

1. Add a hidden input to your form and give it a name and an id :

   `<input type="hidden" id="IsFormer" name="IsFormerValue" value="">`
2. Add on click attribute for both radio buttons :

   `<input type="radio" id="Former" name="IsFormer" onclick="ToggleIsFormer('Yes')">`

   `<input type="radio" id="NotFormer" name="IsFormer" onclick="ToggleIsFormer('No')">`
3. Add the function in Javascript :

   `function ToggleIsFormer (Value) {
       document.getElementById('IsFormer').value = Value;
   }`
4. Finally, in `PHP` you check the value with the name of the hidden input **and not the name of the radio buttons**.

> Here is the above steps on your code (**try doing it your self first ;)** ) :

---

```
<form method="POST" id="ipad" name="ipad" action="list.php">
    <input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'First Name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name';}" value="First Name" id="fname" name="fname" class="inputtext">
    <input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Last Name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Last Name';}" value="Last Name" id="lname" name="lname" class="inputtext">
    <input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" value="Email" id="email" name="email" class="inputtext">
    <input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Code') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Code';}" value="Code" id="code" name="code" class="inputtext">

    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="news" name="news" onclick="ToggleWithNews()">
    <div class="radiotext">Sign up?</div>

    <input type="hidden" id="WithNews" name="WithNewsValue" value="No">
</form>

<script>
    function ToggleWithNews () {
        document.getElementById('WithNews').value = 'Yes';
    }
</script>
```

**Done!!!**

---

> **My note :** If you have only on option and the viewer can toggle on or off that option, you should use 2 radio buttons on for `Yes` and one for `No`, because one radio button will be unable to un-check once it has been checked.
>
> **Or**
>
> If you want to only add on input for that option, you should be using a `checkbox` input, since this can be checked and unchecked at any time.

---

**Hope my answer helped you :)**